# Unable to uninstall Microsoft's Keyboard Drivers in Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard

I installed the Microsoft's Keyboard drivers for my Natural Ergonomic 4000.

My customized keyboard is now broken.
I want to uninstall the drivers. I removed the buttons for MS keyboard at Preferences, but this did not remove the drivers.

**How can you uninstall the keyboard drivers?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There should be an uninstaller application in your Utilities folder (/Applications/Utilities/) called either `IntelliPoint UnInstaller.app` or `IntelliType UnInstaller.app`

If those are not available, the extensions are saved in `/System/Library/Extensions` - namely `MicrosoftMouse.kext` and `MicrosoftKeyboard.kext`. In order to safely remove these you will want to run the commands:

`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/MicrosoftMouse.kext`
`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extenstions/MicrosoftKeyboard.kext`

before dragging the files to your trash. If you don't it *may* not allow you to delete them until you restart.

Lastly, under `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` there may be a file called `Microsoft Keyboards.bundle` you can drag to the trash and delete as well.

`kextunload` stands for kernel extension unload.

Credit to [Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) for the details on the installer.